# WPF XAML Properties Description

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, properties, intellisense

Is there any way to show a small popup description of public properties in the VisualStudio XAML editor?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here, do you want to view the public properties of the corresponding .xaml.cs class for your control / window from within xaml?

Comment: I just want to see some description with intellisense in XAML. Just like we can see description (help) while typing in VS.